# Как установить клиент-расширения для PHP?

Tags: php, pecl, centos

Клиент Sphinx?
Пробовал через команду pecl `install sphinx` - не поставил, вывалил ошибки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Забудьте про pecl. Используйте [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Что касается sphinxapi используйте из [оф.источника](https://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/trunk/api/sphinxapi.php), а еще лучше используйте [SphinxQL](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/latest/sphinxql-reference.html) ([доп.материал](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/10/20/sphinxql-query-builder-for-php/)). Так как sphinx продолжает развиваться, а его используют по старым урокам и потом плюются на качество поиска.

Comment: *оф.*. В слове "официальный" одна "ф", ну право дело.